# Almost done with a sorting based on int(I hope). I am having some final troubles with declaring a variable

Tags: c, sorting, integer, declaration

This is a sample from my code that im working on. However i have been trying to understand what to input where I wrote "XXXX" in my sorting alghoritm. Any ideas? Am i doing something or right or is it all wrong. The only error that occurs is "XXXX" is undeclared, but i can not figure out the right input.(the struct name and the "if" is somewhat "hard to read", due to my limited skills in creating code on this website)

code:

```
#define NUM_ITEMS sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]) struct vara
    {
        int nummer;
        char namn[100];
        float pris;
        float volym;
        char typ[100];
        char stil[100];
        char forpackning[20];
        char land[20];
        char producent[50];
        float alkoholhalt;


    } items[100]; for (i = 0; i < 100 && fgets(envara, 512, fp); i++)
    {
        envara[strlen(envara) - 1] = '\0';
        oneline = strdup(envara);


        tok = strtok(oneline, delim);
        items[i].nummer = atoi(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].namn, tok, (max(strlen(tok), sizeof(items[0].namn))));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        items[i].pris = atof(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        items[i].volym = atof(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].typ, tok, strlen(tok));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].stil, tok, strlen(tok));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].forpackning, tok, strlen(tok));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].land, tok, min(strlen(tok), sizeof(items->land)));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].producent, tok, strlen(tok));
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        items[i].alkoholhalt = atof(tok);


        int nummer_sortering(const void* n1, const void* n2)
        {
            items *XXXX = n1;
            items *XXXX = n2;


            return items->nummer - items->nummer;
        }


        printf("\n\nItems sorted by number:");
        qsort(items, NUM_ITEMS, sizeof(items), nummer_sortering);
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
            printf("nummer: %d\n"
                "namn: %s\n"
                "pris: %f\n"
                "volym: %f\n"
                "typ: %s\n"
                "stil: %s\n"
                "forpackning: %s\n"
                "land: %s\n"
                "producent: %s\n"
                "alkoholhalt: %f\n\n",
                items[i].nummer,
                items[i].namn,
                items[i].pris,
                items[i].volym,
                items[i].typ,
                items[i].stil,
                items[i].forpackning,
                items[i].land,
                items[i].producent,
                items[i].alkoholhalt);
```

Comment: `items->nummer - items->nummer` makes no sense. `items` isn't a variable of any kind. `XXXX`'s can be anything you want as long as the two are different. They're just variable names you are using to cast the `void *` to `items *`. Where did you get this code?

Comment: Surely you mean `struct vara *XXXX = n1;` etc.

Comment: I just saw that, thank you. This is my first sorting so trying to figure it out. Yes i mean struct vara. my bad.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how I can solve this? This is my first sorting so take it easy on me

Comment: `envara[strlen(envara) - 1] = '\0';` is dangerous when the input is longer than 511 bytes. This is better: `envara[strcspn(envara, "\n")] = 0`;.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparing function is wrong, the compiler should have given you an error.

What kind of type is `items`? You cannot declare a variable with the name of
another variable. It should be:

```
int nummer_sortering(const void* n1, const void* n2)
{

    struct vara *item1 = n1;
    struct vara *item2 = n2;

    return n1->nummer - n2->nummer;
}
```

Also doing

```
envara[strlen(envara) - 1] = '\0';
```

is not correct. If the input is longer than 511 characters,
`envara[strlen(envara) - 1]` won't be a newline. The best way to remove the
newline (if any) is:

```
envara[strcspn(envara, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Also

```
strncpy(items[i].producent, tok, strlen(tok));
```

You are using `strncpy` wrong. The point of `strncpy` is that you limit the
numbers of bytes to copy based on the size of the destination. You are limiting the
number bytes based on the length of the source. If it's longer than what
`producent` can hold, then you will have a buffer overflow. Also remember that
`strncpy` does not necessarily write the `'\0'`-terminating byte. You have to
make sure that for yourself:

```
size_t max = sizeof items[i].producent;
strncpy(items[i].producent, tok, max);
items[i].producent[max - 1] = '\0';
```

Also you should check that `strtok` doesn't return `NULL`. If it does, that
means that the line does not have the format you're looking for. In this case
you can dismiss the line and read the next one.

Comment: I think the  #define NUM_ITEMS is wrong aswell. What should it be?

Comment: @emano12 the `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` way to get the numbers of elements only works with pure arrays, if won't work with pointers. `NUM_ITEMS` is not wrong, as far as I can see `items` is a global variable and it is an array, `NUM_ITEMS` should return you the number of items.

Comment: But this doenst work #define NUM_ITEMS sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]) Am i thinking wrong?

Comment: @emano12 if `items` is an array, it will work, if `items` is **not** an array, it won't work. The code you've posted in the question is different to the one in your answer, so right now I'm confused what is what. I'd suggest that you create a new question with your new code. And before doing that, please read [mcve].